# Symbology lettertype

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, font

Does anyone know how to increase the lettertype when I am working in the print layout to export it as an image? My symbology in my normal working mode I have lettertype 10 (which is big enough to read), though, in the print layout I can barely read the lettertype.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Go back to your main window, click on the layer that contains the symbiology, and edit click on the `layer labeling option`. It is the `abc` button that is under neither the `clock`.  There you can edit the properties of the characters. Check [this](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/label_tool.html) out for more information.

Answer (score 5):

The lettersize is defined in point there is conversion to get the measure in mm. If you set 10 then the result should be 10 point.

If when you are dooing your layout think it seems too small and you don't want to change the style of your map in qgis, there is a workaround.

One quick solution is to reduce the width and height of the layout you will export and augment the dpi proportionnaly. You will get a png with the same number of pixel but with bigger lettersize.